# Android Studio Gradle Error - Versions Crashes and BaseGameUtils

Tags: gradle, crash, version, basegameutils

Firstly this problem emerged without no rhyme or reason. Probably it appeared after last updating.

The warning I get says "I have a version conflict" but i can't find the old version code block anywhere. here picture..

[Click here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAGft.png)

And when i glance the BaseGameUtils(Android High Scores Project) gradle file, i see this,

[Click here..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61VvC.png)

the code block in this picture ,

```
if (!project.hasProperty('appcompat_library_version')) {
        ext.appcompat_library_version = '25.0.+'
    }
    if (!project.hasProperty('support_library_version')) {
        ext.support_library_version = '20.0.+'
    }
```

when i try to change `appcompat_library_version` or `support_library_version`, i get error. also i don't know `.+` means. is it mean "it doesn't matter?" anyway, for example i changed it `25.3.+` than i got same error. when i click "sync now",
v24\valuesv24.xml named xml file open. and i get error.

maybe the problem is not about that i last mentioned. but however i want to share this.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding BaseGameUtils seems to use the sdk version 25.0.1 and the rest of your project is compiled using version 25.3.1. The versions do not match and that is why you are having that issue.

You could try to change the target sdk version :)